# Regular expression to allow alphanumeric with space and disallow certain special characters(<>&;)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need helping in constructing a regular expression thats allows alphanumeric characters and disallows following special chararcters **<>&;** . Please help.

Comment: Alphanumeric means numbers and letters, so an alphanumeric regex would already disallow those symbols. Am I correct in saying that you only want alphanumeric characters? If so then `[A-Za-z0-9]*` is the way to go.

Comment: then allow everything **except** the characters you disallow

Comment: @dotconnor So, i want only those 4 characters to be disallowed. eg. 'Abc@123' is a valid and `Abc<123` is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex matches everything except `<>&;`:

```js
const regex = /^[^<>&;]*$/

console.log(regex.test('Abc@123'))
console.log(regex.test('Abc<123'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches alphanumeric and spaces:

```js
var regex = /[a-z0-9\s]*/i;
var string = "All Alphanumeric";
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

If you want to allow certain symbols, just add those to the regex (e.g. the below regex also allows the email `@` symbol and the `.`:

```js
var regex = /[a-z0-9\s@\.]*/i;
var string = "valid@email.domain";
console.log(string.match(regex));
```